# How to have spring security context in child context

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss7.x, spring-ws

I'm trying to have spring security context in child context, so I could have url security on the servlet context file.

I have:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp-soap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

on web.xml, general security configuration on spring-security.xml and

```
<!-- Authorization configurations -->
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    create-session="never"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <security:custom-filter
        position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="serviceAuthenticationFilter"/>

    <security:intercept-url
        pattern="/GetForbiddenUrl" access="hasRole('roleThatDoesntExist')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</security:http>
<!-- annotation security -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

on the myapp-soap-servlet.xml. It doesn't work but fails with

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/my-app/v1/soap]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 192) JBWEB000284: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

However, if I move `<security:http>` part to spring-security root context configuration, everything works. Shouldn't it work the way I try? How can I get url-based security in my child context?

I also tried combining the context files into one, but the same problem seems to occur.

Comment: Are you sure that your spring-security.xml is picked up by spring?

Comment: @MaksymDemidas yes, as moving the `http` part results in all directives being used, in both parnt and child context

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The DelegatingFilterProxy will by default look in the root ApplicationContext which means by default you need to place your `<http>` configuration there (it is what creates the springSecurityFilterChain).

However, you can specify use that `DelegatingFilterProxy` a different `ApplicationContext` by specifying the contextAttribute for it to use. To do this update your web.xml as shown below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.myapp-soap</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

A similar example using Spring Security 3.2+'s AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer can be seen below:

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String getDispatcherWebApplicationContextSuffix() {
        // NOTE: if you are using AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer or
        // AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer You probably
        // want this value to be "dispatcher"
        return "myapp-soap";
    }

}
```

This works because it modifies the name of the ServletContext attribute that `DelegatingFilterProxy` uses to lookup the `ApplicationContext`. Instead of using the default value which discovers the root `ApplicationContext` it now uses the attribute that your `MessageDispatcherServlet` is using (thus pointing to the child context).

Note that `MessageDispatcherServlet`'s (or any subclass of `FrameworkServlet` such as `DispatcherServlet`) stores the `ApplicationContext` in the `ServletContext` using the attribute name `"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT." + <servlet-name>` where `<servlet-name>` is the name of the servlet. So in this instance, the attribute that must be configured is `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.myapp-soap`. If you changed the servlet-name `from myapp-soap` to `spring-servlet`, then you would use `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring-servlet` instead.

PS I think the subject should read "How to have spring security context as child context"

Answer (score 2):

`<security:http>` will have to go to the main application context instead of the child (servlet) context, because this security namespace element creates the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean, which is looked up by `DelegatingFilterProxy` in the main context. As its javadoc clearly states:

> web.xml will usually contain a `DelegatingFilterProxy` definition, with the specified `filter-name` corresponding to a bean name in Spring's **root application context**.

Comment: This is not fully true, as commented in answer, you can also make the DelegatingFilterProxy to look for springSecurityFilterChain bean in web context if needed.